# Not able to switch to the frame in salesforce lightening page

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, domxpath

Please find the attached screenshot and code which i have used.

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@title,'Deploy Data Set')]")));

```html
<div class="slds-template_iframe slds-card" force-aloha-page_aloha-page=""><iframe height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true" id="vfFrameId_1536136086228" name="vfFrameId_1536136086228" allowfullscreen="true" force-aloha-page_aloha-page="" allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *" title="Deploy Data Set"></iframe></div>
```

[image]

Comment: @theGuy can you please look into the issue.

Comment: can you clarify what you want?

Comment: you need to add hidden text input and use jquery or javascript on select add with comma seprated in hiden input. I hope it help

Comment: @SamDeveloper can you please provide code what i need to do because i don;t know javascript

Comment: if order is same you can selectByIndex .

Comment: @Abhishek_Mishra
index will not work as option tag does not contains index attribute.

Comment: you can try By.cssSelector(.slds-select.slds-select1)

Comment: @Amit : having Index attribute is not necessary or required. You can see a list of Options in html. WebDriver takes care of this once you selectByIndex.

Comment: Actually in selenium docs below definition is written so I though index attribute is must.

public void selectByIndex(int index)
Select the option at the given index. This is done by examining the "index" attribute of an element, and not merely by counting.

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html#selectByIndex-int-

Comment: @Amit  try
   {
   
   Select select = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector((".slds-select.slds-select1")))));
   
   select.selectByVisibleText("Destination connection");
   }
   
   catch (Exception e)
   {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
   }

Comment: @Amit this is not working.

Comment: i am not getting any exception as well

Comment: @Abhishek_Mishra can you provide the solution of this.

Comment: Can you provide any URL that we can access to see the complete html? @AnuragShrivastava

Answer (score 0):

Use this: [jsfiddle.net/pn7e3b2u](https://jsfiddle.net/pn7e3b2u/21/)

```js
var select = document.querySelector('.slds-select.slds-select1');
select.addEventListener('change',function(){
  var result = [];
  var options = this && this.options;
  var opt;

  for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    opt = options[i];

    if (opt.selected) {
      result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
    }
  }
  alert( result );
});
```

```html
<div class="slds-form--stacked slds-grid slds-wrap" role="form">
                                <div class="slds-form-element slds-m-top--large slds-size--3-of-6">
                                    <label class="slds-form-element__label dsLabel" for="selectSample1">Destination Salesforce Organization</label>
                                    
                                      <div class="slds-form-element tooltipIcon">
                                        <div class="slds-form-element__icon slds-align-middle">
                                            <img alt="Table" class="slds-button__icon" src="/resource/1530008060000/pdri_sprint17__SLDS_Resource/assets/icons/utility/info_60.png">
                                        </div>
                                      
                                        <div class="slds-popover slds-popover--tooltip slds-nubbin--left-top toggle slds-hide" id="tooltipDestination" role="tooltip" style="position: absolute;top: -49px;left: 30px;float: left;min-width: 312px;">
                                           <div class="slds-popover__body">Specifies the organization to copy data to. Use Ctrl+click to select up to five destinations.</div>
                                        </div> 
                                        </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-m-top--small"><select id="j_id0" name="j_id0:theForm:targetList" class="slds-select slds-select1" multiple="multiple" size="3"> <option value="a02m00000086vRZAAY">Local connection</option>
 <option value="a02m00000086vReAAI">Destination connection</option>
</select>
                                    <input id="valholder" type="hidden" name="selval">
                                    </div>
                                </div>   
                            </div>
```